Where did my staged/unstaged file listing go for SourceTree?
I now only see the individual file diff, not the listing of files which used to be where the orange "CHANGES.md" is now.
Moving the grippy to the right of the sidebar does not help expose the file listing nor does tinkering with the "Pending files, sorted by path" setting.


Found this issue https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Can-t-see-quot-Staged-files-quot-list-for-my-commit/qaq-p/2747354

Thanks, but that seems to be suggesting to move the sidebar which is what I tried and it doesn't work

Also found an open bug ticket https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-8146

If you want to put that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct. Downgrading SourceTree as discussed there helped reveal a grippy which I could actually use. Thank you!!

There's a recently opened bug ticket SRCTREE-8143 that I found in the support forum that describes the same issue.
At this time, according to the ticket, the workaround has been to downgrade to version 4.2.7
